# How do I make my custom field look like a regular inputField?

Tags: visualforce

I've built my own custom lookup with code like this:

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!rf_Proposal__c.Billing_Address__c}" required="true"/>

<apex:inputText id="vField_PreferredName" 
    title="Preferred name" value="{!rf_Proposal__c.DBA__r.Name}"/>                  
<apex:image url="/s.gif" alt="Lookup (New Window)" styleClass="lookupIcon"  
    onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" 
    onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';"
    onclick="javascript:showLookupForId()" title="Lookup (New Window)" />

<apex:inputfield value="{!rf_Proposal__c.Agency__c}" required="false"/>
<apex:inputfield value="{!rf_Proposal__c.Revenue_Type__c}" required="false"/>
```

However, the UI comes out like this:

[image]

As you can see the picture, the image link extends to the middle of the screen, forcing the next inputField onto the next line.

What am I missing here??

Comment: I think it is html problem, use proper hierarchy of apex pageblock and pageblocksection

Comment: Use Html table to align the fields evenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it shouldn't be difficult and you have to wrap up the elements wisely. Have a look at the below sample code. I actually used your markup to generate this example

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Some Field</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:inputText id="vField_PreferredName" title="Preferred name" accesskey="" />
                        <apex:image url="/s.gif" alt="Lookup (New Window)" styleClass="lookupIcon" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onclick="javascript:showLookupForId()"
                        title="Lookup (New Window)" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick.  Would you point out what my mistake was?  In my case the entire set of inputFields, inputText, etc... was wrapped in an `outputPanel`.